# How do I add a second variable value to the jQuery widget 'Autocomplete'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using the jQuery ‘Autocomplete Widget’ for a number of years now. This has always been done but passing a value with ‘term’ to the PHP SQL code like this;

```
$( "#cs1" ).autocomplete({
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 3,
        source: "gethint.php",

        select: function( event, ui ) {
                // This if undes the readonly on the Fname input field below
                if ( ui.item.label == 'NONHAM' ) {$('#Fname').prop('readonly', false);}
                  $( "#cs1" ).val( ui.item.label ); 
                  $( "#hints" ).val( ui.item.value );
                  $( "#Fname" ).val( ui.item.desc );
                  var nc = $( "#thenetcallsign" ).html();
                     //return false;
                 }
    })
    
    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
               return $( "<li>" )
               .append( "<a>" + item.label + " --->  " + item.desc + "</a>" )
               .appendTo( ul );
            };
});
```

But now I have to add another condition to the SQL code to return a more detailed value. The value for this additional condition is;

```
var nc = $( "#thenetcallsign" ).html();
```

The problem is I don’t know how to add this to ‘term’ or a separate variable and pass it to gethint.php using the ‘Autocomplete’ widget.

Once I get the extra value to the PHP program I know what to do.

Would somebody please explain or show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to stringify it but pass the `extraParams`

```
extraParams: { type: "CoolCode" },
```

```js
var nc = $("#thenetcallsign").html();
$("#cs1").autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 3,
    source: "gethint.php",
    extraParams: {
      nc: nc
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      // This if undes the readonly on the Fname input field below
      if (ui.item.label == 'NONHAM') {
        $('#Fname').prop('readonly', false);
      }
      $("#cs1").val(ui.item.label);
      $("#hints").val(ui.item.value);
      $("#Fname").val(ui.item.desc);
      var nc = $("#thenetcallsign").html();
      //return false;
    }
  })
  .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
      .append("<a>" + item.label + " --->  " + item.desc + "</a>")
      .appendTo(ul);
  };
});
```

Comment: This did it. I'm still testing but it looks to have solved all the issue and it taught me something. Best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

`source` could be a [function](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) in order to get more flexibility

```
$( "#cs1" ).autocomplete({
 /* ... */
        source: function(request, response) {
              $.getJSON( "gethint.php", {
                   term: request.term ,
                   nc:  $( "#thenetcallsign" ).html()
              }, response );
        },
 /* ... */
});
```